# Unable to delete blank page after Table

Tags: google-docs

In [this google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FbZU3YqNYVnESuba3qR_9vdrrikIefcrLh0Nf_WcUv0/edit?usp=sharing) that has a blank second page, I can't seem to find a way to delete it (assuming I can't change the table in any way).

It doesn't seem to be a newline or a whitespace character.  But, never the less I can't delete it.

[image]

Curious enough, there seems to be the same thing at the top of the page:

[image]

Any idea how to get rid of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks that Google documents requires a paragraph before an after a table, so to avoid having a blank page after a table, reduce the table or the page margins to leave enough space for the "after table paragraph" (you could try set the last paragraph font size to the smaller allowed font size).

Related

- [Always a blank line above where I insert a table?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/12153/88163)