# Cannot get rid of some space/margins

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace, formatting

I'm working on my resume in Google Docs (Word processing) and I'm trying to add my name + personal information at the top, but I'm seeing a line of space above it.

As you can see, I'm trying to get the job done using tables (will be whiting the table borders afterwards). I got it to look how I want using headers, but I heard that some ATS (applicant tracking systems) omit the information in headers so I'm trying to recreate the look all in the body.

I looked everywhere in Google Docs on deleting the space/margin at the top but I can't figure it out.

[image: Resume]

Comment: Could you share a dummy document with the issue reproduced? It would be much easier to help you this way. Please have a look [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) for general instructions on how to share.

Comment: @marikamitsos https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CRq7Kk5YOUV471l-wWqL480C2cmzKVzMchJ-SKwz5RU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: After having a look at your document I believe it is doable. Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxx6M.png) what you are looking for? If yes let me know so I can turn it to a proper answer. Would any of the proposals suit you? One can always play around more. After all, it is a resume.

Answer (score 0):

Use the document header to add the content that you want to be included at the top of the page.

The above because paragraph should be included above and below a table. The same occurs with other elements like images.

Related Q/A

- [Always a blank line above where I insert a table?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/12153/88163)
- [How can I align a table so that text floats around it in Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74870/88163)
- [Unable to delete blank page after Table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/120840/88163)

Reference

- [Add or remove headers, footers & page numbers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/86629?hl=en)